# What are the registry entry "SlateEnable" in AutoRotation key used for

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Some entries are self-explanatory, I may have discovered some through trial and error, but I have not connected any dots reliably for "SlateEnable".

Bottom line question, what does "SlateEnabled" in the AutoRotation effect?

In the registry "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation" there are some entries.
For clarification, I was using a Surface Go. Not sure if this holds true for other devices. Also, it seems I had to have the keyboard cover disconnected before slide out buttons/settings would take effect.

1) Enabled - This bit would toggle as I would enable/disable Rotation Lock.
2) LastOrientation - This seems to correspond to the "DEVMODE" orientation value from the get settings for the screen. 0 = 0 degrees, 1 = 90 degrees, 2 = 180 degrees, and 3 = 270 degrees.
3) SensorPresent - It is a 1 for the tablet and 0 for my desktop. Makes sense.
4) SlateEnable - It looks like it changes as the Enabled changes. Again, not sure what this is used for.

Comment: Probably disables (greys out) a button in auto rotate settings.

Comment: I can confirm on a Surface Book device that SlateEnable does not disable (grey out) the Rotation Lock button.  I set the registry value of `SlateEnable` to 0, restarted the device, and it did not grey out the icon, even when I set `Enable` to 0.